# Let $T_n=\bigg(\frac{n!}{1*3*5*7....(2n+1)}\bigg)^2$ what is the infinite sum $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} T_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

I tried pairing up terms in numerator and denominator and came up with
$$
T_n=\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{n}\Big(\frac{i}{2i+1}\Big)\bigg)^2
$$

Then I thought of taking $\log$ on both sides but nothing seemed to simplify as I needed to find
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} T_n 
$$

and not
$$
\prod_{n=0}^{\infty} T_n
$$

It's also enough to characterise an upper/lower bound for the infinite sum, an exact value isn't required

Please help! I am back on square 1

---

EDIT: Here's the entire question:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to show convergence or do you try to get a good numerical approximation?

Comment: Wait, I'll post the entire question.

Comment: Hint: what's $\tfrac{T_{n+1}}{T_n}$? What's $\tfrac{T_1}{1-1/4}$, and why am I asking that?

Comment: Well, $\dfrac{T_{n+1}}{T_n} < \dfrac{1}{4}$.

Comment: @J.G. I didn't get why you're asking that? One of the solutions mentioned it too but I didn't get any of that. Could you please post it as an answer?

Comment: Since $\tfrac{T_{n+1}}{T_n}=\left(\tfrac{n+1}{2n+3}\right)^2<\tfrac14$, by induction $T_n<\frac{T_1}{4^n}$, so $\sum_{n\ge1}T_n<\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{T_1}{4^n}$,

Comment: Sorry, that upper bound should be $\sum_{n\ge1}\tfrac{T_1}{4^{n-1}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the ratio of successive coefficients is a rational function of n, this sum can be view as one particular value of a [Generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function). More specifically:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} T_n= _3F_2(1,1,1;\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};\frac{1}{4})$$
This specific form can be found with the method described in the Wikipedia article.
By using the [Euler's integral transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function), we get
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} T_n=\frac{\Gamma(3/2)}{\Gamma(1)\Gamma(1/2)}\int_0^1 (1-t)^{-1/2}._2F_1(1,1;\frac{3}{2};\frac{t}{4})dt.$$
Apply [Euler's transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) to get
$$_2F_1(1,1;\frac{3}{2};\frac{t}{4})=(1-\frac{t}{4})^{-1/2}._2F_1(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};(\sqrt\frac{t}{4})^2).$$
This is a [special case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) where
$$_2F_1(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};(\sqrt\frac{t}{4})^2)=\frac{\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{t}{4}}}}{\sqrt{\frac{t}{4}}},$$
that is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} T_n=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 (1-t)^{-1/2}(1-\frac{t}{4})^{-1/2}\frac{\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{t}{4}}}}{\sqrt{\frac{t}{4}}}dt$$
or better:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} T_n=2\int_0^1\frac{\arcsin{\sqrt{\frac{t}{4}}}}{\sqrt{t(1-t)(4-t)}}dt$$